# Validate a form by passing the form name as a constructor

Tags: javascript, forms, oop, validation

I'm trying to validate a form by passing the form node through a constructor. I know using OO is a bit over the top but it's a request. I've got the code below, but when I try to alert out the values of the text boxes in function(form), they are coming up as undefined.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function Validator(fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    Validator.prototype.validate = function (form) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.fields.length; i < l; i++) {
            alert(this.fields[i].value);
            if (this.fields[i].value == 0) {
                alert("The field  is empty");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var validator = new Validator(["username", "password"]);

    function runValidate(form) {
        validator.validate(form);
    }
</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
<form NAME="AbbeyRoad">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Please login</legend>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="username"><span class="shortkey">U</span>sername:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" accesskey="u">
        </div>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="password"><span class="shortkey">P</span>assword:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" accesskey="p">
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="login" value="Login" id="login" onClick="runValidate(this.form)">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
alert(this.fields[i].value);
```

to:

```
alert(form[this.fields[i]].value);
```

and this:

```
if (this.fields[i].value == 0) {
```

to:

```
if (form[this.fields[i]].value == 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! That worked. By the way, looking at the code, is there any improvements I should make? Obviously its better to do this without OO, but I was wondering if I need to use prototype here?

Comment: Your code is well written, I don't see any harm in using prototype here. All I would say is to remember that functions are themselves objects, and any kind of object is particularly costly to instantiate performance wise, but for smaller apps, clarity is arguably more useful.